# Get cell address of a defined cell in excel by excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If lets say I define cell "B6" name as value_date
How can i get cell address "B6" from a excel formula ?

Comment: How do you define a cell as "value_date" in Excel? Please provide more context.

Comment: Use this formula `=CELL("address",Value_Date)`

Answer (score 1):

If by "define cell B6 as value_date" you mean that you create a named range that refers to B6 and has the range name "value_date", then you can use this formula to return the address of the named range:

=CELL("address",value_date)

Be aware that if the named range contains more than one cell, this formula will return the address of the top left cell of the range.

In the screenshot below, cell C6 has the formula as per above.

[image]

Edit after comment:

If the range name is stored as text in a cell, you can use the Indirect() function to evaluate the cell text as a range.

```
=CELL("address",INDIRECT(A1))
```

To get the row of value_date via the text in cell A1, use `=row(indirect(A1))`

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: thanks guys .. both solution works good.. I wanted to make it more dynamic .. Is it possible to take value_date as a text from a different cell. for example -- cell "A6" has text - value_date .. I was trying this -- =SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(ROW(text(A6,1)),COLUMN(text(A6,1))),"$","")  ...But I am getting error .. I understand the error is due to row() and column() function are unable to understand text and they want a cell reference.. Is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: I addressed your comment. If that answers your question, please mark the answer, as shown in the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`=ADDRESS(ROW(value_date),COLUMN(value_date))`